# Strimzi Kafka Zookeeper not starting

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, strimzi

i'm trying to deploy kafka using strimzi, but zookeeper keep throwing following exception

```
Failed to verify hostname: 10.244.0.14 (org.apache.zookeeper.common.ZKTrustManager) [ListenerHandler-my-cluster-zookeeper-0.my-cluster-zookeeper-nodes.kafka.svc/10.244.1.20:3888]
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: 
Certificate for <10.244.0.14> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [*.my-
cluster-zookeeper-client.kafka.svc, 
my-cluster-zookeeper-client, my-cluster-zookeeper-1.my-cluster-zookeeper-nodes.kafka.svc.cluster.local, 
my-cluster-zookeeper-1.my-cluster-zookeeper-nodes.kafka.svc, my-cluster-zookeeper-client.kafka, my-cluster-zookeeper-client.kafka.svc, 
*.my-cluster-zookeeper-nodes.kafka.svc, 
*.my-cluster-zookeeper-nodes.kafka.svc.cluster.local, *.my-cluster-zookeeper-client.kafka.svc.cluster.local, my-cluster-zookeeper-client.kafka.svc.cluster.local]
```

below is the deployment file i'm using

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
kind: Kafka
metadata:
  name: my-cluster
spec:
  kafka:
    version: 3.1.0
    replicas: 2
    listeners:
      - name: plain
        port: 9092
        type: internal
        tls: false
      - name: external
        port: 9094
        type: loadbalancer
        tls: false
    config:
      offsets.topic.replication.factor: 2
      transaction.state.log.replication.factor: 2
      transaction.state.log.min.isr: 2
      default.replication.factor: 2
      min.insync.replicas: 2
      inter.broker.protocol.version: "3.1"
    storage:
      type: ephemeral
  zookeeper:
    replicas: 2
    storage:
      type: ephemeral
```

this is how i created strimzi cluster operator

```
kubectl create -f 'https://strimzi.io/install/latest?namespace=kafka' -n kafka
```

Comment: This is a problem of how your DNS works and how ZooKeeper does the TLs hostname verification. There are multiple issues and discussions on the Strimzi GitHUb where this is discussed and where the workaround in disabling the TLS hostname verification in ZooKeeper is described. Alternative is to fix your DNS to match what ZooKeeper expects.

Comment: Thank you @Jakub , can you please elaborate which DNS? You mean kub cluster DNS?

Comment: Yes, correct. ZooKeeper will do a reverse DNS query for the IP address where it tries to connect. And that does not seem to match any of the expected addresses. This should go against the Kube DNS.